# Template for slug

Tags: templates, slug

I am using the "Edit Author Slug" plugin to provide public profile pages on my site using the following structure: **mysite.com/users/username**.

Now, I want to show a list of all users on **mysite.com/users/**. But this returns a 404 because the "users" path is only a slug created by the plugin.

Does WP provide the possibility to create slug templates (just like tag templates)? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a Page with the users slug, then using a custom Page Template to provide the functionality you want to display all the users.